# Download websites web pages in parallel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, parallel-processing

I have the following code and it works fine when I loop through one by one using `foreach`, but when I change it to use `Parallel.ForEach` I'm getting errors. Trying to figure out how I can correct this. FYI the `dParms` list contain unique id's.

The error I'm getting is

> Error writing to path..... ErrorMessage:Item has already been added.
> Key in dictionary: 'IIS_WasUrlRewritten' Key being added:
> 'IIS_WasUrlRewritten',

```
        private void GeneratePages(RequestStatus response, string localDir, List<Parameters> dParms, int total, DateTime generatedTime)
    {
        int current = 0;
        Parallel.ForEach(dParms, curJob =>
        {
       
            try
            {
                DownloadPage(localDir, curJob, generatedTime);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.Status = false;
                response.Message = ex.Message;
               
            }
            finally
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref current);
                if (current % 10 == 0)
                    //to do: Send Progress to UI
            }
        //});
    }

    private string DownloadPage(string localDir, Parameters p, DateTime generatedTime)
    {
        string strExtension = "html";
        string url = string.Empty;

        url = this.Url.Action("MyAction", "Home", new { area = "", @id = p.MyId, @generatedTime = generatedTime }, this.Request.Url.Scheme);

        var document = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
        
        string strFileName = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        strFileName = strFileName.Substring(0, strFileName.IndexOf("generatedTime") - 1);
        string strDiskFileName = strFileName.Replace(".aspx?", "");
        strDiskFileName = strDiskFileName.Replace("?", "");
        strDiskFileName = strDiskFileName.Replace(".aspx", "");
        strDiskFileName = strDiskFileName.Replace("&", "");
        strDiskFileName = strDiskFileName.Replace("=", "");
        strDiskFileName = strDiskFileName.Replace("%20", "");
        strDiskFileName += "." + strExtension;
        document.Save(localDir + strDiskFileName);


        return url;
    }
```

Comment: What line of code throws this exception?

Comment: What's `HtmlWeb`? Also, a search for "IIS_WasUrlRewritten" finds that it has something to do with URL Rewriting in IIS; maybe the requests are hitting IIS faster than it can handle?

Comment: Thanks @hereicmonkey HtmlWeb comes from the nuget package HtmlAgilityWebPack. Hmm how would i test that it's due to requests hitting iIS faster than it can handle?